# How much damage does a melee attack do?

Tags: doom-2016

In DOOM 2016, specifically in multiplayer, how much damage does a melee attack do?

I'm talking about normal melee hits, not glory kills.

Is it a set amount of damage, or does it depend on some factor?

I'm asking because I want to know if I should shoot or punch if I have my combat shotgun out, and suddenly come face to face with an enemy.

Comment: I can't seem to find any hard coded numbers, at least from some quick research. i imagine if you launch a private game, with damage indicators enabled, though, it might tell you how much a melee strike does.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Oh, I didn't know that was possible. Maybe I'll try that. I would need to arrange someone to join though right? I'm assuming procedure games aren't available to the public?

Comment: Not yet I don't think, private Deathmatch is coming but not quite yet, if memory serves

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Melee attacks do 25 damage. This is easy to test now that Multiplayer has a "Practice Mode".

It should be noted though that my original "use shotgun or melee" question was misguided. Melee attacks do not seem to interrupt shotgun "cooldown". A better flow seems to be "shotgun-melee-shotgun" for maximum damage.

Answer (score -2):

No you can't kill other players by  just melee attacks. The damage caused is around 25% in one hit. Till you give 4 punches the opponent will kill you. If your shotgun is out then you'll have to stick with the pistol or just run like hell and find ammo.

Comment: Sources? Posting an answer on just opinion doesn't really help

Comment: @Draken Was going to say the same. I have in fact punched people to death. This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @Carcigenicate so the answer ist just wrong?

Comment: @sschrass I was waiting for them to clarify or respond back. As it stands, I'd say yes, this answer is just wrong.